# PostgreSQL run query for today's date

Tags: php

I found a lot of questions similar to mine, but none seemed to work 
I have this query

```
$query= "SELECT * from jazz WHERE parsing_date = (todays date) ";
```

I want "`parsing_date`" to equal to today's date I work on PostgreSQL.
For it to get from my database all records that have today's date. Also `parsing_date` has date format.

Comment: SELECT NOW() ? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No I want it to be like where parsing_date = (todays date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL there are next [date-constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-datetime.html):
CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or universal function **now()**.

Try next query in your case:

```
$query = "SELECT * from jazz WHERE parsing_date=CURRENT_DATE";
```